# Site is fast on localhost but slow on server

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using XAMPP on Windows 10 to serve a website, and the website is very fast on localhost, but very slow on my public domain address. Why is that? My internet speed should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to load all CSS files in starting and put all js files at the end and remove unwanted comments or files. this might help to improve the speed of your site. and also the resolution or maybe size of images which you use in your site it will make much faster your website.